# Rounding a number to decimal places and keeping a trailing zero

Tags: number-representation, rounding, output-formatting

It's often useful for me to round numbers to some decimal place for printing on a graph or figure. I usually do this by:

```
RoundedNumber = Round[NumberToRound, 0.001]
```

But if the resultant rounding is say `1.2` from `1.19`, I would like to keep the trailing zero; so `1.20`. The reason being is that I represent by errors in bracketed notation -- where the number in brackets represents the error in the last digit. E.g.  `1.20(2)` -- so as you can see it is important to keep the trailing zero as `1.2(2)` has a different meaning to `1.20(0)`

Does anyone  a way I can do this?

Comment: `1.99` cannot round to `1.2`. Did you mean `1.19`? Take a look at `NumberForm`.  `NumberForm[1.19, {2, 2}]` = `1.20`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Eugh, yes! Sorry that is a typo! And brilliant thanks for that, I've never had much success with `NumberForm[...]` until now!

PS corrected in the original question...

Comment: Notice that NumberForm[1.186, {2, 2}] is also 1.20 while the correct answer seems to be 1.19 - is this true? Sure that NumberForm[1.186, {3, 2}] gives 1.19, but you must find some way of calculating the number of digits as input to NumberForm.

Comment: Also try `NumberForm[1.186, {\[Infinity], 2}]` for precisely two digits to the right of the decimal dot.

Comment: @Schumacher Congratulations. Full solution, simple, practical and works also with numbers whose absolute values are smaller than 1. Should post, for future reference, since the accepted solution does not correspond to the convention on rounding numbers. I did not find this use of infinity in the argument list in the documentation for NumberForm[ ].

Comment: @VitoVanin I fail to see how the accepted answer "does not correspond to the convention on rounding numbers". From what I can see it is the definition of arithmetic rounding -- there are other conventions if you are referring to those?

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Notice that Bill Watts added the function rounded1[ ], which does conform with the convention - just compare the outputs of rounded[ ] and rounded1[ ], for instance try Table[ rounded1[1.18649603, i], {i, 8}] .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may mostly do what you want.
With `num` specifying the number you are rounding and `prec` specifying the number of digits past the decimal:

```
rounded[num_, prec_] := 
 PaddedForm[num, {IntegerPart[Log[10, Abs[num]]] + prec, prec}]

rounded[1.19, 2]
(*1.20*)

rounded[1.19, 3]
 (*1.190*)

rounded[500.5556877, 3]
(*500.560*)

rounded[500.5556877, 5]
(*500.55570*)
```

If you do not require a trailing zero and want regular rounding you can add 1 to first element of the `PaddedForm` list:

```
rounded1[num_, prec_] := 
 PaddedForm[num, {IntegerPart[Log[10, Abs[num]]] + prec + 1, prec}]
```

Comment: Nice answer and a useful function! Thanks.